# require minimum 100 characters length in a textarea/form validation

Tags: jquery, validation

How to require a minimum of 100 characters in the textarea?.. thanks a lot !

this is my code that right now is only checking if there is SOME(any) text in the field:

```
<form name="register" id="register" action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true) ; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return doUserRegister();" >
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register_post" />
            <fieldset>
<div class="clearfix">                                 
<label for="address">Location *</label>
<div class="input">
<textarea id="address" class="xlarge contact-message" name="address" id="address" value=""></textarea>
</div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text_error_required = 'This field is required' ;
    var text_valid_email    = 'Invalid email address' ;
</script>
```

and the register.js goes like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#address").bind({
"blur": function (e) {
    text_validation($(this));
},
"focus": function (e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('error') ;
    $(this).parent().find(".help-inline").remove() ;
}
});

function doUserRegister() {
var error = false;
if ( !text_validation($("#address")) ) {
error =  true;
}

return !error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
  if(document.register.address.value.length<100){
     error = true;
    }
```

But you should really consider validating every field you want differently. for example make four fields with stree, zip, country, city and validate each on its own.

Also you can look into form validation libs, I personally like [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Cheers

Comment: script stops working when adding that "if" :( is it possible to add the length<100 to my current if? : if (!text_validation($("#address")) ) {
error =  true;
}

Comment: where is the function text_validation anyway?

Comment: in register.js  "and the register.js goes like this"

Comment: yeah but you are calling the function text_validation() which is not defined in your code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo osc_current_web_theme_js_url('register.js') ; ?>"></script>